# intent service not populating screen

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, intentservice

I have it set up so that when the user hits "clock in" it starts the intentservice, the intent service then updates the ui, the only problem is its not working.... here is my code for the main activity page :

```
    package com.famousmods.payme;

    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;

public class PayTracker extends Activity {
private ResponseReceiver receiver;
private static double Reserve;
private static int Reserve1;
public static double money;
public static double counter;
private static int go;
private static int countdown;
public static int convert;
public static double HW;
public static double OTW;
public static double HPD;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_tracker);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 // register reciver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
 // Receive messages from options page
   double pHW, pOTW, pHPD;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    pHW = intent.getDoubleExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HW, 0);
    pOTW = intent.getDoubleExtra(Options.MESSAGE_OTW, 0);
    pHPD = intent.getDoubleExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HPD, 0);
    if(pHW != 0){
        HW = pHW;
        OTW = pOTW;
        HPD = pHPD;
    }
 // Color buttons
    Button buttonc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockin);
    buttonc.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    Button buttond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockout);
    buttond.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);



     final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockout);
     b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {


             }
     });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_pay_tracker, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    };
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {

    //Start IntentService
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, SimpleIntentService.class);
    msgIntent.putExtra(SimpleIntentService.PARAM_IN_HW, HW);
    msgIntent.putExtra(SimpleIntentService.PARAM_IN_OTW, OTW);
    msgIntent.putExtra(SimpleIntentService.PARAM_IN_HPD, HPD);
    startService(msgIntent);//}   
}

public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.famousmods.payme.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Update UI, new "message" processed by SimpleIntentService
        final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourpay);
        t1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        final TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.payper);
       String end = intent.getStringExtra(SimpleIntentService.PARAM_OUT_END);
       String result = intent.getStringExtra(SimpleIntentService.PARAM_OUT_RESULT);
       t2.setText(result);
       t1.setText(end);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();  


}
```

}

And Here is my intent service page, its set up so that swhen the intent starts it starts a timer that every 20ms should send the new intent back to the activity page, here is the code:

```
    package com.famousmods.payme;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.famousmods.payme.PayTracker.ResponseReceiver;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SimpleIntentService extends IntentService {

public static final String PARAM_OUT_END = "end";
public static final String PARAM_OUT_RESULT = "result";
public static final String PARAM_IN_HW = "hourly wage";
public static final String PARAM_IN_OTW = "overtime";
public static final String PARAM_IN_HPD = "hours per day";
public static String end;
public static String result;
private static double Reserve;
private static int Reserve1;
public static double money;
public static double counter;
private static int go;
private static int countdown;
public static int convert;

public SimpleIntentService() {
    super("SimpleIntentService");

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // recieve from paytracker
    double HW = intent.getDoubleExtra(PARAM_IN_HW, 1);
    double OTW = intent.getDoubleExtra(PARAM_IN_OTW, 1);
    double HPD = intent.getDoubleExtra(PARAM_IN_HPD, 1);
    // Calculate pay per second
    final double PPS = (HW/3600);
    final double DPPS = (PPS/50);
    final double OTPPS = (OTW/3600);
    final double DOTPPS = (OTPPS/50);
    final double HPDPS = (HPD*3600);
    final double DHPDPS = (HPDPS*50);

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    if(DHPDPS==0){
                        money = (DPPS+Reserve);
                        Reserve = (money);
                        end = String.format("%1f", money);
                       //t1.setText("$" + end);
                    }else if(counter > DHPDPS && DOTPPS != 0 && DHPDPS != 0){
                        money = (DOTPPS+Reserve);
                        Reserve = (money);
                        end = String.format("%1f", money);
                        //t1.setText("$" + end);
                    } else{

                        money = (DPPS+Reserve);
                        Reserve = (money);
                        end = String.format("%1f", money);
                        //t1.setText("$" + end);
                    }
                    counter++;
                    //if(counter == 3000)
                    //   t.cancel();

                    // Display pay per second
                    if(counter <= DHPDPS || DHPDPS == 0){
                        result = String.format("%.8f", PPS);
                    }else{
                    //  t2.setText("Your pay per second is: $"+result2);
                        result = String.format("%.8f", OTPPS);
                    }

                 // Broadcast intent
                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                    broadcastIntent.setAction(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
                    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_END, end);
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_RESULT, result);
                    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                }
            }; 
        }
    }, 20, 20);
}

}
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: You have created sendMessage(View view) function for starting service but from where you are calling that function in your PayTracker  activity ??

Comment: @AndroidCoder i guess i am confused on what your asking

Comment: You had created sendMessage function right ??

Comment: @AndroidCoder Yes 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clockin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/clockout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:textColor="#DCDCDC"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/clock_in" />